# Process.Start in MAC OS using .NET core gives error - No such file or directory

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

I'm creating a .NET core console application to run a command .

```
public bool RunCommand()
{
    try
    {
        var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("exec", "cal")
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false
        };

        var proc = new Process { StartInfo = procStartInfo };
        proc.Start();

        // Get the output into a string
        output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        return proc.ExitCode == decimal.Zero ? true : false;
    }
    finally
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error -

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ResolvePath(String filename)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at HockeyApp.Enablers.IosCodeSign.ProcessManager.RunCommand(String command, String& output)
   at HockeyApp.Enablers.IosCodeSign.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I even tried like -

```
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cal")
```

no luck.

Anything am I missing ?

Comment: Calc is a Windows program. OSX has "Calculator" though.

Comment: actually its "cal". my bad - typo. i just edited the question. In any case, its not working.

Comment: exec is a bash shell command, not a program.  Look in /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 5):

I just remove the `"exec",` in the constructor, put a `var` before the `output` and the code work as well, available on https://github.com/fontanaricardo/RunCommand